# Question about usage of $\leq$ in definition of Nash equilibrium

Tags: definition, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Quick definition:

> Given $g$, a strategy N-tuple $u^* = (u_1^*,...,u^*_N)$ is said to be
>   a Nash equilibrium if:
>
> $$J_i(u_i^*, u^*_{-i}) \leq J_i(u_i, u^*_{-i}), i \in N$$
>
> where $J$ is the cost function, $u^*_{-i}$ is strategy for all players
>   except for $i^{th}$ player.

**What $\leq$ as used in the definition? How do you compare two vectors?**

For example, given matrix game (say hawk dove game)

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} (0,0) & (-5,-2) \\ (-2, -5) & (-4,-4) \end{bmatrix}$$

Claim: two pure strategy nash equilibrium are (-5,-2), (-2,-5) where each entry represents the cost = negative of gain

How do you compare $J_1 = (-5,2)$  and $J_2 = (-4,-4)$ as according to the definition? Clearly, we cannot say $J_1 \leq J_2$ if we were evaluating each term pairwise, nor can we say $J_1 \geq J_2$...how can we say that solution that gives $(-5,-2)$ a nash equilibrium?

Comment: You misunderstood the subscript of $J$. In the definition, $J_i$ means the $i$th component. For example, consider the game you wrote. Here, the vector $(0,0)$ means the cost to row player is 0 and the cost to the column player is also 0. Each row (column) represents an action for the row (column) player.

Comment: $J_i$ is not a vector, it is a function that maps profiles of strategies into a real number: $J_i:\times_{i\in\mathbb{N}} U_i\to \mathbb{R}$, so that $\le$ is the standard ordering. The definition just says that, given the strategies of all other players ($u_{-i}$), $u_i$ has to minimize the cost of $i$, and this has to simultaneously hold for all players $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the position with row player 1 choosing the first option and column player 2 choosing the second option, the costs to each are represented with $(-5,-2)$, so the cost to player $1$ is $-5$ (i.e. the payoff is $+5$) and $J_1(1,2) = -5$, while the cost to player $2$ is $-2$  (i.e. the payoff is $+2$) and $J_2(1,2) = -2$.

Given that the column player 2 is choosing the second option, this is an equilibrium for row player 1, since $J_1(1,2) \le J_1(1,2)$ trivially while  $J_1(1,2) \le J_1(2,2)=-2$.

Given that the row player 1 is choosing the first option, this is an equilibrium for column player 2, since $J_2(1,2) \le J_2(1,1) = 0$ while $J_1(1,2) \le J_1(1,2)$ trivially.

So this is a Nash equilibrium since neither player can reduce their individual cost (increase their individual payoff) by changing strategy.